# In a View page within MVC, what is the preferred way to deal with empty variables

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications

When using the MVC design pattern I usually try to make my view files as simple as possible.

Therefore in my **View** I try not to have lots of code like this:

```
if page title exists

    display page title

else 

    display 'default page title'

end if
```

Instead, in my **Controller** I might use code like this:

```
if no page title is specified

    page title = 'default page title'

end if

load the view (pass page title as a parameter)
```

Is this the best way to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping this if-else condition in the controller level is a better idea than moving into views. (if you can otherwise it's alright)

It will make your views look good !!!!